# why Java designers don't make list like this ---new ArrayList("1","2")

Tags: java, list, arraylist

If I design the List ,I will make it like this- `new ArrayList("1","2")`.
give it a constructor,and add something into it immediately.
Why Java don't do it in this way?

Comment: I guess the main reason is when the Collections API was written there was not vargs or generics.  The Collections API dates way back to Java 1.2

Comment: I would argue that if you already know what are the elements of the list (hardcoding them in), you could just use an array. ArrayLists are more for when you can't know in advance how many elements would be in the list as it's more efficient than creating and discarding arrays on your own as more elements need to be added. So the need to have such a constructor is negated, because arrays are better for fixed known lists. Right?

Answer (score 7):

Because there is no constructor that will accept two Strings or vargs. To overcome this you can call: `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1", "2"))`

Comment: +1 for taking this question seriously

Comment: Nice use of `Arrays.asList`, have to make a mental note of that

Comment: It would be best to parametrize the `ArrayList` with the `String` type.

Comment: @arshajii Good spot, updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: How would this perform compared to simply adding elements to the ArrayList?

Comment: @ADTC You probably wouldn't see a noticeable difference, especially with this few elements. Nevertheless, if performance is a concern, I would definitely omit the intermediate `Arrays.asList` and just add the elements directly.

Comment: Of course, but performance is usually gauged in terms of a large number of elements, like millions and millions of them. You can create a Java program to easily generate another Java program with millions of elements to gauge it. _PS:_ A problem many Java beginners have is they don't fully understand the cost of code they write, and how they can write more efficient code. I realized this as I got involved in projects where efficiency is of importance.